# KonvaJS zIndex: Background image either covers foreground polygons or appears as black box onload

Tags: javascript, z-index, onload, konvajs

I'm trying to get a background image (png, map of Europe) to display behind a bunch of polygons (countries) for which I have mouseover/mouseout/mousedown events. I've tried putting the background pic in a separate layer & assigning zIndex values to each layer, and I've tried setting zIndex on the image itself and/or the rectangle to which I've added it (-1, in those cases), without success. The following are my latest attempts:

Here is Demo for JSFiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kushalbacancy/2twL8n07/)

http://leslieasmith.coffeecup.com/konvaJStest11.html), zIndex in two layers (background: 0; layer w/ polygons: 2); polygons load--I see a quick flash before the background image covers them--but changing zIndex doesn't affect layer order.

Chrome warning: "Konva warning: Node has no parent. zIndex parameter is ignored."

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    var width = 1054;
    var height = 779;

    var startFill = '#FF0';
    var mouseoverFill = '#FFF';
    var newFill = '#F00';

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var background = new Konva.Layer({
        zIndex: 0
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer({
        zIndex: 2
    });

    // add background image
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var map = new Konva.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            image: imageObj,
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
        // add image to layer
        background.add(map);
        // add layer to stage
        stage.add(background);
    };
    imageObj.src = 'pix/ushist1a_v3_Ls6_map_background.png';

    var poly0 = new Konva.Line({
        name: 'Ireland',
        points: [164.4, 132.9, 163.05, 131.25, 161.2, 130.5, 160.6, 131.4, 159.75, 131.75, 158.9, 133, 158.75, 134.4, 158.15, 136.15, 157.3, 137.4, 156.15, 137.65, 156.65, 136.75, 157.8, 132.05, 157.75, 131.5, 156.3, 131.35, 153.8, 131.9, 153.2, 131, 150.35, 131.9, 148, 133.1, 146.85, 133.25, 145.4, 135.2, 145.6, 136.25, 145.1, 136.85, 143.05, 138.2, 139.95, 139.15, 140.05, 140.65, 141.9, 141.2, 142.9, 142, 144.25, 141.95, 146.2, 142.55, 146.05, 143.55, 144.6, 145.2, 139.8, 146.8, 139.6, 147.7, 138.9, 149.1, 135.6, 147.95, 131.35, 147.35, 131.05, 145.65, 125.75, 143.45, 123.9, 144.65, 122.1, 146.45, 121.6, 150.25, 120.45, 149.3, 118.35, 149, 119.2, 151.4, 123.7, 153.45, 123.55, 154.95, 119.35, 156.05, 117.95, 157.55, 115.7, 158.25, 115, 159.9, 115.9, 161.9, 116.9, 162.55, 116.4, 163.75, 119.35, 164.45, 119.2, 166.2, 126.4, 168.85, 126.6, 170.25, 125.4, 170.85, 122.15, 171.2, 119.85, 172.5, 118.3, 175.8, 116.55, 177.55, 111.75, 180, 119.6, 181.2, 124.4, 178.5, 123.6, 181.3, 125.5, 182.15, 125.55, 182.6, 117.2, 182.2, 113.55, 181.35, 109.7, 184.5, 108.95, 186.1, 108.05, 186.6, 106.75, 185.8, 105.15, 185.95, 103.75, 185.25, 101.85, 186, 100.6, 187.9, 106.6, 189, 106.6, 190.25, 103.15, 190.75, 100.35, 192.45, 99.55, 193.75, 101.15, 194.1, 101.35, 195.7, 101.8, 195.8, 107.6, 195.75, 107.25, 197.25, 104.8, 197.6, 100.7, 199.35, 101.7, 199.6, 108.4, 199.4, 108.55, 200.25, 107.55, 201.55, 106.05, 201.2, 104.3, 201.6, 104.5, 202.4, 104.15, 203.4, 106.65, 203.05, 108.6, 203.35, 109.25, 204.2, 110.35, 204.75, 112.5, 204.05, 113.75, 204.65, 121.25, 204.4, 123.35, 203.4, 124.2, 202, 124.6, 200.1, 125.4, 200.7, 125.35, 202.05, 126.2, 202.85, 129.65, 202.25, 131, 200.9, 133.1, 201.85, 134.2, 201.05, 135.35, 199.45, 136.15, 198.85, 142.25, 199.25, 145.25, 198.95, 148.2, 199.85, 149.7, 201.05, 151.45, 201.5, 152.65, 200.1, 152.45, 197.55, 155.3, 193.75, 157.1, 190.45, 159.25, 188.15, 160.4, 186.3, 161.75, 176.8, 162.75, 176.65, 164.25, 173.05, 163.55, 164.7, 164.25, 162.9, 165.85, 162.55, 166.35, 162.7, 170, 161.6, 171.2, 159.4, 174.3, 159.45, 176, 158.25, 177.8, 154.15, 177.45, 151.4, 176.6, 150.35, 173.3, 150.1, 175.25, 148.15, 176.4, 144, 175.1, 140.7, 174.5, 137.9, 171.2, 135.55, 165.35, 135.85, 163.4, 136.75, 161.7, 137, 161.45, 136.05, 164.7, 133.9, 164.4, 132.9],
        fill: startFill,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        closed : true
    });
    //Ireland mouse events
    poly0.on('mouseover', function() {
        if (this.fill() == startFill) {
            this.fill(mouseoverFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly0.on('mouseout', function() {
        if (this.fill() == mouseoverFill) {
            this.fill(startFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly0.on('mousedown', function() {
        this.fill(newFill);
        layer.draw();
    });

    var poly1 = new Konva.Line({
        name: 'Great Britain',
        points: [202, 78.5, 202.05, 79.65, 203.15, 81.75, 196.6, 83.3, 195.3, 87.65, 196.45, 88.9, 195.95, 89.2, 194.65, 88.6, 193.9, 88.75, 193, 91.95, 194.4, 92.45, 196.9, 92.6, 196.3, 93.55, 195, 93.85, 196.15, 94.6, 194.45, 96.05, 193.95, 96.85, 193.75, 98.35, 193.25, 98.35, 192.1, 99.1, 191.85, 100, 190.85, 100.55, 189.95, 101.85, 188.8, 104.85, 186.4, 104.85, 185.05, 105.3, 185, 106, 187, 106.7, 186.65, 108.8, 188.5, 111.65, 191.1, 110.8, 193.65, 109.35, 194.1, 109.2, 194.25, 109.65, 193.9, 110.8, 189.15, 116.75, 187.85, 119.1, 187.55, 120.05, 186.7, 121.05, 185.55, 123.45, 185, 125.25, 186.2, 125.3, 186.5, 126.25, 186, 127.6, 183.1, 130.4, 180.2, 135.25, 179.95, 136, 181.4, 136.35, 182.4, 135.55, 183.9, 133.05, 188.05, 127.85, 188.8, 124.9, 188.65, 123.1, 188.7, 122.15, 193.4, 119, 192.8, 120.4, 190.15, 123.6, 189.45, 126.05, 190.15, 125.4, 190.85, 125.45, 191.45, 124.55, 192.1, 124.3, 193.25, 125.6, 193.75, 125.4, 194.6, 122.55, 196.15, 124.1, 197.2, 125.7, 195.9, 125.7, 195, 126.6, 194.3, 127.7, 193, 131, 193.4, 132.2, 194.45, 133.6, 194.15, 136, 192.35, 137.7, 188.05, 143, 187, 144.7, 186.5, 146.8, 185.4, 145.2, 184.65, 146.35, 184.9, 151.95, 185.55, 153, 186.2, 152.9, 186.8, 149.8, 187.35, 149.1, 188.2, 149, 191.15, 152.8, 192.25, 153.65, 193.3, 152.45, 193.8, 150.75, 198.95, 152.5, 203.15, 151.65, 203.7, 151, 205.55, 150.45, 210.2, 152.1, 209.35, 152.65, 208.35, 152.45, 206.05, 153.65, 201.7, 158.9, 200.85, 160.6, 201, 162.4, 202.05, 164.85, 202.25, 166.85, 202.5, 167.2, 203.05, 166.6, 203.7, 170.05, 207.2, 169.65, 209.65, 168.1, 210.5, 168.75, 209.2, 169.9, 207.95, 173.9, 206.35, 174.9, 204.8, 177.45, 206.85, 178.65, 205, 180.15, 202.9, 183.65, 203.25, 184.85, 204.25, 185.75, 203.25, 186.1, 201.7, 187.75, 192.45, 185.3, 188.85, 186.4, 185, 188.3, 177.95, 192.75, 178.95, 193.75, 183, 192.25, 185.7, 192.4, 185.5, 194.6, 184.4, 199.4, 184.4, 200.55, 185.55, 201.85, 181.7, 206.55, 173.15, 209.7, 164.6, 211.8, 165, 212.7, 165.05, 214.35, 165.65, 217.15, 166.05, 217.95, 167.4, 218.6, 169.35, 218.25, 172.15, 216.7, 174.6, 216.3, 175.3, 216.95, 175.1, 220.15, 175.75, 221.3, 178.6, 222.15, 180.85, 220.95, 181.6, 220.95, 182.2, 221.6, 184.65, 227.25, 186, 228.2, 188.05, 228.55, 189.8, 227.8, 191.45, 226.25, 195, 225.15, 199.4, 223.15, 199.1, 224.9, 197.45, 226.55, 192.45, 230.45, 191.35, 232.1, 190.45, 232.9, 186.9, 232.85, 179.25, 231.05, 175.5, 230.95, 173.5, 233.2, 170.65, 234.35, 168.15, 237.35, 154.85, 246.2, 150.3, 248, 148.9, 249.8, 148.65, 250.85, 149.85, 249.35, 150.95, 249, 153.15, 251.35, 154.45, 251.35, 154.85, 252.65, 156.25, 251.8, 157.6, 249.85, 160.7, 249.1, 162.9, 246.65, 170.3, 248.35, 174.75, 251.3, 176.6, 251.95, 178.8, 250.15, 181.35, 244.55, 182.2, 244.5, 184.05, 245.05, 186.9, 244.4, 191.15, 244.15, 194.1, 249.65, 194.4, 249.8, 195.45, 248.6, 197.9, 248.5, 200.25, 249.8, 201.75, 249.5, 201.5, 247.5, 207.85, 248.7, 208.7, 248.05, 210.6, 247.65, 211.15, 246.5, 211.45, 245.15, 212.75, 246.65, 214.25, 247.5, 216.55, 247.45, 216.9, 248.45, 218.05, 249.8, 227.95, 250.15, 230.65, 251.45, 243.55, 250.1, 244.05, 249.2, 250.25, 246.2, 251.4, 243.55, 250.95, 242.4, 244.7, 241.5, 241.75, 240.65, 242, 238.35, 241.15, 236.55, 243.9, 236.1, 244.65, 234.85, 246.05, 233.7, 245.65, 232.9, 244.4, 232.05, 246.15, 231.25, 247.85, 230.9, 248.85, 231.85, 251, 231.55, 251.75, 230.2, 251.65, 227.9, 252.8, 228.2, 254.8, 227.6, 257.2, 225.55, 259.55, 220.5, 260.5, 216.85, 260.5, 212.8, 258.85, 209.3, 256.85, 207.3, 255.1, 206.2, 251.9, 205.55, 246.45, 205.65, 243.3, 208.55, 242.5, 207.35, 239.25, 206.15, 240.6, 204, 244.3, 201, 245.15, 199.6, 245.65, 197.35, 244, 193.7, 242.8, 192.15, 242.35, 190.75, 241.25, 189.8, 238.6, 186, 239.75, 185.6, 241.85, 188.5, 244.7, 189.55, 244.85, 189.4, 245.05, 185.6, 243.7, 183.85, 242.2, 180.45, 242.15, 176.95, 241, 173.9, 240.4, 171.25, 239, 167.85, 236.6, 166.2, 233.55, 164.95, 232.9, 163.95, 232.65, 160.75, 231.6, 157.8, 230.95, 154.45, 230.85, 151.9, 232.1, 143.15, 230.45, 141.2, 228.7, 138.05, 227.85, 135.15, 222.5, 130.35, 221.4, 129.75, 217.25, 130.4, 214.15, 128.75, 214.15, 128.35, 215.15, 126.75, 216.9, 125.7, 218.7, 125.6, 221.1, 125.95, 223.35, 125.45, 221.85, 121.8, 220.9, 121.05, 220.85, 119.75, 222.9, 120.4, 224.4, 119.75, 226.3, 118.15, 227.05, 116.45, 231.1, 112.95, 232, 110.95, 233.55, 108.65, 235.1, 105.35, 239, 102.55, 240, 98.5, 239.7, 96.55, 236.2, 95.45, 233.25, 95.25, 228.7, 93.55, 226.2, 93.4, 223.9, 92.1, 215.55, 92.95, 213.65, 93.9, 212.95, 92.95, 213.9, 91.6, 214.1, 90.9, 212.15, 91.05, 212.5, 90.05, 215.75, 89.9, 218.2, 88.45, 214.8, 87.25, 215.6, 85.65, 215.8, 86.05, 218.55, 83.95, 223.4, 82.4, 225.85, 79.8, 229.1, 78.65, 231.25, 73.55, 229, 72.15, 225.85, 72.5, 222.85, 72.45, 220.5, 71.85, 216.95, 71.85, 216.8, 71.45, 213.15, 69.55, 210.8, 69.65, 207.55, 72.65, 206.5, 75.7, 204.05, 75.3, 203.35, 78.2, 202, 78.5],
        fill: startFill,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        closed : true
    })
    //Great Britain mouse events
    poly1.on('mouseover', function() {
        if (this.fill() == startFill) {
            this.fill(mouseoverFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly1.on('mouseout', function() {
        if (this.fill() == mouseoverFill) {
            this.fill(startFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly1.on('mousedown', function() {
        this.fill(newFill);
        layer.draw();
    });

    // add everything to the layer
    layer.add(poly0);
    layer.add(poly1);
    layer.add(text);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
```

In konvaJStest12 (jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/las794/6tnshu2v/; live: http://leslieasmith.coffeecup.com/konvaJStest12.html), which has one layer, zIndex in either Image object or Rect object (-1; same result in either case). Polygons load & are visible, but background (in rectangle shape) shows only as black box (no fill specified for rect, just image: imageObj). If I mouse over polygons, background suddenly displays and all's right w/ the world--but why? And how do I make the background show up onload?

Chrome warning: "Konva warning: Node has no parent. zIndex parameter is ignored."

Chrome error: "Uncaught TypeError: t.getParent is not a function | at Konva.Layer.add (konva.min.js:26) | at Image.imageObj.onload (konvaJStest12.html:59)"

Here's the relevant code:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<script>
    var width = 1054;
    var height = 779;

    var startFill = '#FF0';
    var mouseoverFill = '#FFF';
    var newFill = '#F00';

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = 'pix/ushist1a_v3_Ls6_map_background.png';
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var map = new Konva.Image({
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            image: imageObj,
            width: width,
            height: height
        });
        // add the image to the layer
        layer.add(imageObj);
        // add the layer to the stage
        stage.add(layer);
    };

    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        fillPatternImage: imageObj,
        //fillPatternOffset: { x : -220, y : 70},
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        zIndex: -1 //doesn't work here or in Image object
    });

    // add the shape to the layer
    layer.add(rect);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);

    var poly0 = new Konva.Line({
        name: 'Ireland',
        points: [164.4, 132.9, 163.05, 131.25, 161.2, 130.5, 160.6, 131.4, 159.75, 131.75, 158.9, 133, 158.75, 134.4, 158.15, 136.15, 157.3, 137.4, 156.15, 137.65, 156.65, 136.75, 157.8, 132.05, 157.75, 131.5, 156.3, 131.35, 153.8, 131.9, 153.2, 131, 150.35, 131.9, 148, 133.1, 146.85, 133.25, 145.4, 135.2, 145.6, 136.25, 145.1, 136.85, 143.05, 138.2, 139.95, 139.15, 140.05, 140.65, 141.9, 141.2, 142.9, 142, 144.25, 141.95, 146.2, 142.55, 146.05, 143.55, 144.6, 145.2, 139.8, 146.8, 139.6, 147.7, 138.9, 149.1, 135.6, 147.95, 131.35, 147.35, 131.05, 145.65, 125.75, 143.45, 123.9, 144.65, 122.1, 146.45, 121.6, 150.25, 120.45, 149.3, 118.35, 149, 119.2, 151.4, 123.7, 153.45, 123.55, 154.95, 119.35, 156.05, 117.95, 157.55, 115.7, 158.25, 115, 159.9, 115.9, 161.9, 116.9, 162.55, 116.4, 163.75, 119.35, 164.45, 119.2, 166.2, 126.4, 168.85, 126.6, 170.25, 125.4, 170.85, 122.15, 171.2, 119.85, 172.5, 118.3, 175.8, 116.55, 177.55, 111.75, 180, 119.6, 181.2, 124.4, 178.5, 123.6, 181.3, 125.5, 182.15, 125.55, 182.6, 117.2, 182.2, 113.55, 181.35, 109.7, 184.5, 108.95, 186.1, 108.05, 186.6, 106.75, 185.8, 105.15, 185.95, 103.75, 185.25, 101.85, 186, 100.6, 187.9, 106.6, 189, 106.6, 190.25, 103.15, 190.75, 100.35, 192.45, 99.55, 193.75, 101.15, 194.1, 101.35, 195.7, 101.8, 195.8, 107.6, 195.75, 107.25, 197.25, 104.8, 197.6, 100.7, 199.35, 101.7, 199.6, 108.4, 199.4, 108.55, 200.25, 107.55, 201.55, 106.05, 201.2, 104.3, 201.6, 104.5, 202.4, 104.15, 203.4, 106.65, 203.05, 108.6, 203.35, 109.25, 204.2, 110.35, 204.75, 112.5, 204.05, 113.75, 204.65, 121.25, 204.4, 123.35, 203.4, 124.2, 202, 124.6, 200.1, 125.4, 200.7, 125.35, 202.05, 126.2, 202.85, 129.65, 202.25, 131, 200.9, 133.1, 201.85, 134.2, 201.05, 135.35, 199.45, 136.15, 198.85, 142.25, 199.25, 145.25, 198.95, 148.2, 199.85, 149.7, 201.05, 151.45, 201.5, 152.65, 200.1, 152.45, 197.55, 155.3, 193.75, 157.1, 190.45, 159.25, 188.15, 160.4, 186.3, 161.75, 176.8, 162.75, 176.65, 164.25, 173.05, 163.55, 164.7, 164.25, 162.9, 165.85, 162.55, 166.35, 162.7, 170, 161.6, 171.2, 159.4, 174.3, 159.45, 176, 158.25, 177.8, 154.15, 177.45, 151.4, 176.6, 150.35, 173.3, 150.1, 175.25, 148.15, 176.4, 144, 175.1, 140.7, 174.5, 137.9, 171.2, 135.55, 165.35, 135.85, 163.4, 136.75, 161.7, 137, 161.45, 136.05, 164.7, 133.9, 164.4, 132.9],
        fill: startFill,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        closed : true
    });
    //Ireland mouse events
    poly0.on('mouseover', function() {
        if (this.fill() == startFill) {
            this.fill(mouseoverFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly0.on('mouseout', function() {
        if (this.fill() == mouseoverFill) {
            this.fill(startFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly0.on('mousedown', function() {
        this.fill(newFill);
        layer.draw();
    });

    var poly1 = new Konva.Line({
        name: 'Great Britain',
        points: [202, 78.5, 202.05, 79.65, 203.15, 81.75, 196.6, 83.3, 195.3, 87.65, 196.45, 88.9, 195.95, 89.2, 194.65, 88.6, 193.9, 88.75, 193, 91.95, 194.4, 92.45, 196.9, 92.6, 196.3, 93.55, 195, 93.85, 196.15, 94.6, 194.45, 96.05, 193.95, 96.85, 193.75, 98.35, 193.25, 98.35, 192.1, 99.1, 191.85, 100, 190.85, 100.55, 189.95, 101.85, 188.8, 104.85, 186.4, 104.85, 185.05, 105.3, 185, 106, 187, 106.7, 186.65, 108.8, 188.5, 111.65, 191.1, 110.8, 193.65, 109.35, 194.1, 109.2, 194.25, 109.65, 193.9, 110.8, 189.15, 116.75, 187.85, 119.1, 187.55, 120.05, 186.7, 121.05, 185.55, 123.45, 185, 125.25, 186.2, 125.3, 186.5, 126.25, 186, 127.6, 183.1, 130.4, 180.2, 135.25, 179.95, 136, 181.4, 136.35, 182.4, 135.55, 183.9, 133.05, 188.05, 127.85, 188.8, 124.9, 188.65, 123.1, 188.7, 122.15, 193.4, 119, 192.8, 120.4, 190.15, 123.6, 189.45, 126.05, 190.15, 125.4, 190.85, 125.45, 191.45, 124.55, 192.1, 124.3, 193.25, 125.6, 193.75, 125.4, 194.6, 122.55, 196.15, 124.1, 197.2, 125.7, 195.9, 125.7, 195, 126.6, 194.3, 127.7, 193, 131, 193.4, 132.2, 194.45, 133.6, 194.15, 136, 192.35, 137.7, 188.05, 143, 187, 144.7, 186.5, 146.8, 185.4, 145.2, 184.65, 146.35, 184.9, 151.95, 185.55, 153, 186.2, 152.9, 186.8, 149.8, 187.35, 149.1, 188.2, 149, 191.15, 152.8, 192.25, 153.65, 193.3, 152.45, 193.8, 150.75, 198.95, 152.5, 203.15, 151.65, 203.7, 151, 205.55, 150.45, 210.2, 152.1, 209.35, 152.65, 208.35, 152.45, 206.05, 153.65, 201.7, 158.9, 200.85, 160.6, 201, 162.4, 202.05, 164.85, 202.25, 166.85, 202.5, 167.2, 203.05, 166.6, 203.7, 170.05, 207.2, 169.65, 209.65, 168.1, 210.5, 168.75, 209.2, 169.9, 207.95, 173.9, 206.35, 174.9, 204.8, 177.45, 206.85, 178.65, 205, 180.15, 202.9, 183.65, 203.25, 184.85, 204.25, 185.75, 203.25, 186.1, 201.7, 187.75, 192.45, 185.3, 188.85, 186.4, 185, 188.3, 177.95, 192.75, 178.95, 193.75, 183, 192.25, 185.7, 192.4, 185.5, 194.6, 184.4, 199.4, 184.4, 200.55, 185.55, 201.85, 181.7, 206.55, 173.15, 209.7, 164.6, 211.8, 165, 212.7, 165.05, 214.35, 165.65, 217.15, 166.05, 217.95, 167.4, 218.6, 169.35, 218.25, 172.15, 216.7, 174.6, 216.3, 175.3, 216.95, 175.1, 220.15, 175.75, 221.3, 178.6, 222.15, 180.85, 220.95, 181.6, 220.95, 182.2, 221.6, 184.65, 227.25, 186, 228.2, 188.05, 228.55, 189.8, 227.8, 191.45, 226.25, 195, 225.15, 199.4, 223.15, 199.1, 224.9, 197.45, 226.55, 192.45, 230.45, 191.35, 232.1, 190.45, 232.9, 186.9, 232.85, 179.25, 231.05, 175.5, 230.95, 173.5, 233.2, 170.65, 234.35, 168.15, 237.35, 154.85, 246.2, 150.3, 248, 148.9, 249.8, 148.65, 250.85, 149.85, 249.35, 150.95, 249, 153.15, 251.35, 154.45, 251.35, 154.85, 252.65, 156.25, 251.8, 157.6, 249.85, 160.7, 249.1, 162.9, 246.65, 170.3, 248.35, 174.75, 251.3, 176.6, 251.95, 178.8, 250.15, 181.35, 244.55, 182.2, 244.5, 184.05, 245.05, 186.9, 244.4, 191.15, 244.15, 194.1, 249.65, 194.4, 249.8, 195.45, 248.6, 197.9, 248.5, 200.25, 249.8, 201.75, 249.5, 201.5, 247.5, 207.85, 248.7, 208.7, 248.05, 210.6, 247.65, 211.15, 246.5, 211.45, 245.15, 212.75, 246.65, 214.25, 247.5, 216.55, 247.45, 216.9, 248.45, 218.05, 249.8, 227.95, 250.15, 230.65, 251.45, 243.55, 250.1, 244.05, 249.2, 250.25, 246.2, 251.4, 243.55, 250.95, 242.4, 244.7, 241.5, 241.75, 240.65, 242, 238.35, 241.15, 236.55, 243.9, 236.1, 244.65, 234.85, 246.05, 233.7, 245.65, 232.9, 244.4, 232.05, 246.15, 231.25, 247.85, 230.9, 248.85, 231.85, 251, 231.55, 251.75, 230.2, 251.65, 227.9, 252.8, 228.2, 254.8, 227.6, 257.2, 225.55, 259.55, 220.5, 260.5, 216.85, 260.5, 212.8, 258.85, 209.3, 256.85, 207.3, 255.1, 206.2, 251.9, 205.55, 246.45, 205.65, 243.3, 208.55, 242.5, 207.35, 239.25, 206.15, 240.6, 204, 244.3, 201, 245.15, 199.6, 245.65, 197.35, 244, 193.7, 242.8, 192.15, 242.35, 190.75, 241.25, 189.8, 238.6, 186, 239.75, 185.6, 241.85, 188.5, 244.7, 189.55, 244.85, 189.4, 245.05, 185.6, 243.7, 183.85, 242.2, 180.45, 242.15, 176.95, 241, 173.9, 240.4, 171.25, 239, 167.85, 236.6, 166.2, 233.55, 164.95, 232.9, 163.95, 232.65, 160.75, 231.6, 157.8, 230.95, 154.45, 230.85, 151.9, 232.1, 143.15, 230.45, 141.2, 228.7, 138.05, 227.85, 135.15, 222.5, 130.35, 221.4, 129.75, 217.25, 130.4, 214.15, 128.75, 214.15, 128.35, 215.15, 126.75, 216.9, 125.7, 218.7, 125.6, 221.1, 125.95, 223.35, 125.45, 221.85, 121.8, 220.9, 121.05, 220.85, 119.75, 222.9, 120.4, 224.4, 119.75, 226.3, 118.15, 227.05, 116.45, 231.1, 112.95, 232, 110.95, 233.55, 108.65, 235.1, 105.35, 239, 102.55, 240, 98.5, 239.7, 96.55, 236.2, 95.45, 233.25, 95.25, 228.7, 93.55, 226.2, 93.4, 223.9, 92.1, 215.55, 92.95, 213.65, 93.9, 212.95, 92.95, 213.9, 91.6, 214.1, 90.9, 212.15, 91.05, 212.5, 90.05, 215.75, 89.9, 218.2, 88.45, 214.8, 87.25, 215.6, 85.65, 215.8, 86.05, 218.55, 83.95, 223.4, 82.4, 225.85, 79.8, 229.1, 78.65, 231.25, 73.55, 229, 72.15, 225.85, 72.5, 222.85, 72.45, 220.5, 71.85, 216.95, 71.85, 216.8, 71.45, 213.15, 69.55, 210.8, 69.65, 207.55, 72.65, 206.5, 75.7, 204.05, 75.3, 203.35, 78.2, 202, 78.5],
        fill: startFill,
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        lineJoin: 'round',
        closed : true
    })
    //Great Britain mouse events
    poly1.on('mouseover', function() {
        if (this.fill() == startFill) {
            this.fill(mouseoverFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly1.on('mouseout', function() {
        if (this.fill() == mouseoverFill) {
            this.fill(startFill);
            layer.draw();
        }
    });
    poly1.on('mousedown', function() {
        this.fill(newFill);
        layer.draw();
    });

    // add everything to the layer
    layer.add(poly0);
    layer.add(poly1);
    layer.add(text);

    // add the layer to the stage
    stage.add(layer);
```

The multi-layer approach seems the most logical, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `konva`, `zIndex` is just index of a node in the array of children of a parent Container.

So in this code:

```
var background = new Konva.Layer({
    zIndex: 0
});
```

`zIndex` is ignored, because `background` has no parent Container yet. You can set `zIndex` only AFTER you added it into a Container:

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
   container: 'container',
   width: width,
   height: height
});
var background = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(background);

background.setZIndex(2); // can not do this, bacause stage has only only child

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

background.setZIndex(1); // can do this. background will be above "layer", "layer" will have index 0
```

Just add nodes into parent in correct order.

Comment: That makes sense--unfortunately, the layers are still in the wrong order, background on top of 'layer' (polygons) layer. Here's new code:

(see my "answer" above for revised code)

Answer (score 1):

My comment didn't reproduce the revised code correctly, so here it is again:

That makes sense--unfortunately, the layers are still in the wrong order, background on top of 'layer' (polygons) layer. Here's new code:

```
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var background = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(background);

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    background.setZIndex(0);
    layer.setZIndex(1);

    console.log(background.getZIndex());
    console.log(layer.getZIndex());
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. Fortunately, folks on Gitter got me the rest of the way. My mistake was in the Image Object:
background.add(map); // add image to layer
then:
stage.draw(); // draw image to stage (NOT stage.add(background))